# scala class serialization, impossible to fix SerialVersionUID

Tags: scala, serialization, serialversionuid, remote-actors

I'm currently testing remote actors to communicate between Android and Windows. Actors remote sends differents classes where I set the serialVersionUID.

This is the code of my serialized class:

```
@SerialVersionUID(13.asInstanceOf[Long]) case class IdentifyMessage(userName : String, user : User, code : Int)
```

the problem is that the remote actors debug says there is a problem with incompatible class:

```
caught java.io.InvalidClassException: scala.actors.remote.Node; local class incompatible: 
stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -6610463074147725500, local class serialVersionUID = -7525549079045563153
```

Why my SerialVersionUID doesn't matter for compiler?

How do I do to fix serialVersionUID? or maybe there is an another problem?

thanks

Comment: You can write long literals directly: `13L` is a long value. Shouldn't matter for your problem, though.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason using the long version of 13, 13l, works better:

```
@SerialVersionUID(13l) case class IdentifyMessage(userName : String, user : User, code : Int)
```

Tested in REPL with:

```
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(IdentifyMessage("hei", User(), 8).getClass).getSerialVersionUID()
```

**Update**

I also tried to run it as a program; like this:

```
object SerialTest extends App {
  case class User()
  @SerialVersionUID(13.asInstanceOf[Long]) case class IdentifyMessage1(userName: String, user: User, code: Int)
  @SerialVersionUID(13l) case class IdentifyMessage2(userName: String, user: User, code: Int)
  println("#1 " + java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(IdentifyMessage1("hei", User(), 8).getClass).getSerialVersionUID)
  println("#2 " + java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(IdentifyMessage2("hei", User(), 8).getClass).getSerialVersionUID)
}
```

... and got:

```
#1 6829060442504540290
#2 13
```

Comment: The reason is that it causes the underlying variable to be declared as a long, as serialization is looking for, instead of an int.

Comment: But 13.asInstanceOf[Long] is also a long, still it silently ignores it. In java you would get an error because of non-constant expression. I had to try it in non-REPL environment, but I got the same result.

Comment: Apparently it isn't my class the problem, but a internal class of remote actors.
I think the problem is scala.actors.remote.Node class.

look at this exception: caught java.io.InvalidClassException: scala.actors.remote.Node,

Is there any solution?